# Overriding standard encoding in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

We are running into problems caused by the bug described here:  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6183404

I have already implemented a fix using a custom charset to fix the incorrect mappings.
However this still does not fix the problem for one Java application we are using, as that is hard-coded to use standard "GBK" charset.

Is there any way using `java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider` to override existing, standard charsets?

Comment: Perhaps JRebel? That is capable of changing classes in runtime. That way you could override the classes you want. I never used it, but I always heard positive comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this code in `Charset`, it doesn't look like you can override the standardProvider since it gets searched before any additional ones.

```
if ((cs = standardProvider.charsetForName(charsetName)) != null ||
    (cs = lookupExtendedCharset(charsetName))           != null ||
    (cs = lookupViaProviders(charsetName))              != null)
```

If the application stores the charset name in a field, you could do something nasty with reflection to change it before the application starts up.

Comment: OK, thanks, that is what I suspected, but just wondered if I had missed something.  Seems value is not a field, using decompiler I can see function in class in WAR that is setting this, specifically `if (paramString.equals("936")) return "GBK";`.  Understand I could somehow override this, but would rather not.